# PISO register output is not as expected

Tags: embedded, verilog, fpga

I have a problem in PISO verilog register.
Below is my code

```
`timescale 1ns / 1ps
module PISO(
    input clk,
    input load, 
    input [3:0] d,
    output reg Qout);  

reg [3 : 0]Q;  


always @ (posedge clk)
begin

if ( load  ) 
  Q <= d;
else
begin 
  Qout <= d[3];
  Q<= { Q[2:0] , 1'b0 };
  end
end
endmodule
```

and my testbench

```
`timescale 1ns / 1ps
module PISO_tb();

PISO uut(clk,load,d,Qout);
reg clk;
reg load;
reg [3:0]d;
wire Qout;

initial begin
clk=0;
forever #5 clk = ~clk;
end

initial begin

load = 1;
d[0] = 1'b0;
d[1] = 1'b1;
d[2] = 1'b0;
d[3] = 1'b1;
#6 load = 0;

end
endmodule
```

And it isn't working as it should, please help me with testbench maybe? Because I think the verilog code is okay and it should work properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want the `Qout` signal to be the output of the shift register (`Q`) instead of the input, so that the output toggles instead of remaining at 1.  Change:

```
Qout <= d[3];
```

to:

```
Qout <= Q[3];
```